# Can't assign to ErrorExpression

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I'm using wxPython and I'm trying to derive a class, and use a default value like so:

```
import wx

def TileWindow(wx.ScrolledCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, pos = wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size = wx.DefaultSize, style = wx.HSCROLL | wx.VSCROLL,
                 name = "tileWindow"):
        wx.ScrolledCanvas.__init__(self, parent, id, pos,
                                         size, style, name)
```

The problem is with "style = wx.HSCROLL | wx.VSCROLL". (wx.HSCROLL and wx.VSCROLL are both of type int.) But for this expression, I get an error that says "can't assign to binary operator".

What is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What exactly is the full error you're getting?  Have you tried wrapping the expression in parnetheses? `style = (wx.HSCROLL | wx.VSCROLL)`

Comment: Yes. I then get "can't assign to ParenthesisExpression".

Comment: what kind of code is this ? Is this a Class or a function definition ? Please post minimal code reproducing your problem

Comment: It was supposed to be a class. I fixed it by changing "def TileWindow" to "class TileWindow". Thanks. :)